How to log the time for azure devops work items and tasks
Is there a report/query in Azure DevOps that helps the person in tracking all the timings like adhoc meetings, day offs, actual work time of particular task so that person can have full control over the time of their work.
There will be 2 case scenarios described below:

Case 1: Hours actual work and 2 hours in meeting, we will get 7 hours productivity for that individual person for each individual task.
Case 2: 5 day leave ,26 hrs of work, 2 hrs meeting and gets actual working hours automatically for each sprint at the time of sprint planning meeting.


Hi there, by work and meeting hours, may I assume your actual requirement is a report including the task assignees' daily time spent in work and meeting of their tasks and their accumulated time spent on all tasks in a time range? Have you tried to use Azure DevOps Analytics view with PowerBI?

Hi @user, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to integrate Azure DevOps Analytics view with PowerBI and generate timing reports based the individual daily logging? Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

Per the Working days (days off) information, please note that Azure DevOps manages the information on project team level rather than individual level.

Per the expectation to collect the information of the Meeting and Work time that individual spends on their daily tasks, you may request individual task assignee to populate these fields in their tasks every day, so that you can leverage Azure DevOps Analytics view integrated in Power BI Desktop to generate tables/reports to monitor the working hours per user, per day, per task or the accumulated working hours in a date range. Here are the brief steps as a sample for your reference.

Create custom fields in the Tasks for individual task assignee to log their own daily Meeting and Work hours on each task;



Create an Analytics view with the name of Tasks - Work to collect the values in the fields of Assign To, Work Item Id, Meeting and Work, within the Date range from a history date to present, as the source data to be consumed in Power BI later;


In Power BI Desktop, load the source data from Azure DevOps analytics view Task - Work;



Create new tables to process the source data from Azure DevOps analytics view; below are 3 sample tables generated with DAX expressions for your reference.
User = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Tasks - Work',
    'Tasks - Work'[Assigned To],
    "Total Meeting Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Meeting]),
    "Total Work Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Work])
)


User/Date =
SUMMARIZE(
    'Tasks - Work',
    'Tasks - Work'[Assigned To],
    'Tasks - Work'[Date],
    "Total Meeting Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Meeting]),
    "Total Work Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Work])
)


User/Task = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Tasks - Work',
    'Tasks - Work'[Assigned To],
    'Tasks - Work'[Work Item Id],
    "Total Meeting Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Meeting]),
    "Total Work Hours", SUM('Tasks - Work'[Work])
)




You can create your own tables for reports according to your expectations, but please keep in mind to RESET the Meeting and Work fields of all the team members' tasks every day, so that the daily snapshot values in the task fields are correct.

This Looks promising, will try this out. But from where we need to reset the meeting and work fields? Is it from their assigned task ?

Yes, this demo workflow/repost is based on the daily snapshots of the two fields of each task. Therefore, it requires the values in the two fields to be reset as 0 every day. And the task assignees need to edit the two fields according to their work before the end of the day.

Hi @user, May I know the suggestion to generate reports based on Azure DevOps analytics view could work for you? Thx for the sharing.

Hi, Will try in this week and confirm.

Thank you in advance for taking time to share the update. Cheers.

hey, it works, thank you so much
